# FluiddPI docker build error container restarting

Tags: raspberry-pi

Hey there i have a problem when trying to build the FluiddPI API on my raspberry pi. I followed the steps given in the README.md and installed the requirements beforehand. Everything seems to work until i try to build the respository with the make build command. The download and all goes well but after that I get an error saying the container is restarting as seen below. Does anybody have an idea on how i could fix this i tried with the hlep of ChatGPT, but that didnt help a lot. Just to be clear i'm a beginner and i'd appreciate any help i can get.

This is the console output:

```
 99  363M   99  360M    0     0  1601k      0  0:03:52  0:03:50  0:00:02 145 99  363M   99  362M    0     0  1605k      0  0:03:52  0:03:51  0:00:01 165100  363M  100  363M    0     0  1606k      0  0:03:52  0:03:52 --:--:-- 1673k
docker-compose up -d
fluiddpi-build is up-to-date
docker exec -it fluiddpi-build build
Error response from daemon: Container 4327cf2f2fc48f82b9bacd742ec6baf66d22edde13d6a4f78e28ad54bcd3d79a is restarting, wait until the container is running
make: *** [Makefile:5: build] Error 1
```

This is the repository
https://github.com/fluidd-core/FluiddPI

I tried to install Fluidd on my old Raspberry pi (Raspberry Pi Model B+ V1.2 from the year 2014). I tried using KIAUH to install it but after a lot of troubbleshooting and getting it install completely i gave up on it and tried the FluiddPI Image. I got the Wifi to work insntalling a needed driver (RTL88x2bu) for my wifi adapter, but while trying to further follow the steps specified in the README.md and some troubleshooting with the help of ChatGPT and my basic understanding of it i couldnt get past this point.

I tried to stop and remove the docker, leading me to the same problem.

Thanks in advance,

Ron